# How to install NPAPI plugin in chrome without using manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi

I am able to load NPAPI plugin using extension in chrome, but my requirement is to load *plugin.dll* without extension in chrome.

I have tried the following to load my plugin.dll in chrome:

1. copied my *plugin.dll* and paste it mozilla's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\plugins`.
2. open chrome browser and typed `chrome://plugins` now I can see my *plugin.dll* loaded to chrome and able to run the `test.html`.

Is this the standard way to load the npapi plugin in chrome browser ? If not then please suggest how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to install a NPAPI plugin that is not part of an extension on Windows is to add the correct keys in the windows registry.

From [the mozilla wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#Windows_Installation_Using_the_Registry):

```
HKLM/Software/MozillaPlugins/plugin-identifier

    Descripton: REG_SZ "Description of the Plugin"
    Path: REG_SZ "C:\..Path to the plugin.dll"
    ProductName: REG_SZ "The Plugin Name"
    Vendor: REG_SZ "The Plugin Author/Vendor"
    Version: REG_SZ "0.5.whatever plugin version string"
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but if i have to load the plugin in case i have not installed mozilla firefox. can i load the plugin without using manifest .mson file

Comment: it doesn't matter if you've installed firefox or not; all npapi browsers use that method for finding plugins